# Search Python packages that no other packages depend on

Tags: python, package-management, packages, pip, dependencies

How can I find all Python packages that *no other packages* depend on? I tried [`pipdeptree`](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/) to get dependency trees, but I'm not sure if this is a good starting point and my impression is that it's omitting any package that doesn't have *any* dependencies.

Motivation: I want to delete all packages that have been installed at some point as dependencies, but are no longer in use.

Edit: I'm on Windows 7 and using `pip` (although I'm not sure if this problem is solvable using `pip`).

Comment: Which OS? Which package manager?

Comment: @mashuptwice 
Windows 7 and `pip`! Added this info to the question.